# Разница между классом и структурой в С++

Tags: c++, ооп

Давно мучает этот вопрос, ведь, очевидно, что разница не только в том, какой доступ предоставляется по-умолчанию (без модификаторов доступа) к элементам классов и структур. В стандартной библиотеке есть как классы, так и структуры, например, std::array — это структура, а std::vector — класс. Мне кажется, что разработчики стандартной библиотеки руководствовались при выборе чем-то объективным. В других языках структуры отвечают за value type, а классы за reference type, но, как я понимаю, к С++ это не относится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> разница не только в том, какой доступ предоставляется по-умолчанию (без модификаторов доступа) к элементам классов

Не только к членам, еще к родителям без модификатора доступа. Другой разницы нет.

Строго говоря, структур в языке вообще нет, и слово `struct` создает класс.

> `std::array` — это структура, а `std::vector` — класс

Выбирают на глазок.

[С++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/) (там иногда пишут странные вещи, но здесь я с ними в целом согласен) предлагают два критерия:

- [C.2: Use `class` if the class has an invariant; use `struct` if the data members can vary independently](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-structd)

  Т.е. если поля можно менять как попало - структура, а если есть какое-то условие на содержимое полей ("инвариант"), за которым тип следит сам - это класс.
- [C.8: Use `class` rather than `struct` if any member is non-public](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-class)

  Использовать класс если хотя бы один член не-публичный, иначе структуру.